# nHibernate 4.1.4 is not quoting table name that matches reserved keyword

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using nHibernate 4.1.4 MappingByCode. My Dialect is

```
public class Dialect : NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect
{
    protected override void RegisterKeywords()
    {
        base.RegisterKeywords();
        RegisterKeyword("user");
    }
}
```

My config is setting
config.SetProperty(Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, "keywords");

I have a table named User.

SQL error is thrown that invalid table name User is invalid. nHibernate fails to wrap it in brackets.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords are used for different purpose...

what we need is ad hoc table name escaping

#### [5.3. SQL quoted identifiers](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-quotedidentifiers)

> You may force NHibernate to quote an identifier in the generated SQL
>   by enclosing the table or column name in back-ticks in the mapping
>   document. NHibernate will use the correct quotation style for the SQL
>   Dialect (usually double quotes, but brackets for SQL Server and
>   back-ticks for MySQL).
>
> ```
> <class name="LineItem" table="`Line Item`">
>     <id name="Id" column="`Item Id`"/><generator class="assigned"/></id>
>     <property name="ItemNumber" column="`Item #`"/>
>     ...
> </class>
> ```

I.e. in mapping, we need to escape table name:

```
"`user`"
```

*Keywords, defined in configuration of the dialect, would help NH parser when working with custom **sql** statements. E.g. in `formulas`, `subselects`.*